# AWS Lambda: unable to delete arn because it is a replicated function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to delete an AWS Lambda function through the GUI, but am getting a response: `There was an error deleting your function: Lambda was unable to delete arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:624929674184:function:lambda-auth:1 because it is a replicated function.`

[image]

How can one delete replicated Lambda functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replicated functions are something `Lambda@Edge` uses, so I assume that's the case here even though it's not stated. You should review this document on [how to delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-delete-replicas.html) these. You can't manually delete them at this time:

> **You can delete a Lambda@Edge function only when the replicas of the
>   function have been deleted by CloudFront. Replicas of a Lambda
>   function are automatically deleted in the following situations:**
>
> After you have removed the last association for the function from all
>   of your CloudFront distributions. If more than one distribution uses a
>   function, the replicas are removed only after the function is
>   disassociated from the last one.
>
> After you delete the last distribution that a function was associated
>   with.
>
> Replicas are typically deleted within a few hours.

Note:

> Replicas cannot be manually deleted at this time. This helps prevent a situation where a replica is removed that you're still using, which would result in an error.

Comment: thanks very much! I disabled the associated cloudfront distribution, and once that finishes I'll delete it, and I have a hunch that will allow me to delete the function -- I'll follow up once that's all done

Comment: Yep, deleting my CloudFront distribution allowed me to delete the function -- many thanks!

Comment: I deleted my cloudFront yet couldn't delete the lambda until an hour or so. Finally removed all code from the lambda (except one comment line) and saved it. Then I was able to get it deleted.

Answer (score 13):

I have figured out the solution to **delete Lambda@edge replica.**

1. Firstly, Login to CloudFront Console and go to your **Distribution**.
2. Under the **Behaviors** Tab - tick the listed **Behavior** and **edit**
3. Scroll down to Lambda Function Associations and remove any Association by clicking the **X**.
4. Press **yes,edit** to save the changes.
   --- Now that you have removed the Associations it's time to delete the Lambda@edge replicas
5. Go to Lambda Console and open your lambda( you wish to delete).
6. On the top menus - **Qualifiers** -> **Versions**-> choose the listed drop-down version
   [image]
7. It will open that @edgeLambda Version
8. On the top menus - **Actions** -> **Delete version**
   [image]
9. This way , deleting all the versions - you are left with **$LATEST**
10. Deleting that also - you are finally able to delete the Lambda@edge Function

Note!>  Please remember to delete any IAM Roles and Permissions associated with Lambda@edge Functions.

I hope this will work  :)

Please refer the link [Delete Lambda@Edge Functions and Replicas](https://medium.com/@dheerajarora_6502/deletion-of-lambda-edge-replicas-cloudfront-distributions-aec78b9d0203), you will find it much useful.

Comment: Did you have to wait couple of hours before deleting the versions? I followed your steps but still cannot delete the version (it has been less than 30 minutes since I removed the trigger from cloudfront).

Comment: Follow up; for anyone in this scenario, I had to wait 1 hour before I was able to delete them.

Comment: It's been long I worked on the @edgeLambda, as far as I remember I was able to delete it on the go removing the association from the Cloudfront. I tried doing it again now just to check for you, able to delete the 1 replica out of 3 and on trying deleting the 2 replica ran into error saying can't delete as it is an replicated function , not sure about what is causing this as i remove all the associations already, may be have to wait for a while as you are facing.

Comment: Same error. But it seems the solution is just to wait enough time and try again lol (so I guess I'll wait)

Comment: After deleting old versions and roles and permissions, I waited for about 15 mins and I was able to delete, as suggested. Ty!

Answer (score 3):

If you tried every other answer, and it's still not deleting - wait 5-10 minutes and try again.

Answer (score 0):

[BHEERAJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61454243/3720305) is good, but in my exact case I waited like 6 hours and nothing changed and the error was still ocurring, but then I also removed related S3 buckets (and to remove the bucket, I had to remove items inside it first):

https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3

Then in about half a hour I tried to remove those Lambda functions, and finally it actually deleted.