# aws cdk: Unable to delete lambda edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-edge

Couldn't delete lambda stack via aws cdk:

```
Lambda was unable to delete lambda because it is a replicated function.
```

[image]

Comment: can you add your code? we can't delete lambda@edge until it is completely disassociated from cloudfront!

Comment: Did you take a look at the documentation as was suggested in the error message?

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50748658/2447211

Answer (score 1):

When deleting a CloudFormation Stack with CloudFront resource and associated Lambda@edge - CloudFormation first initiate a delete request for the CloudFront resource and the links to lambda@edge, since the lambda@edge is replicated to edges locations it takes up to a few hours to complete the links deletion.

My workaround is to run the complete clean-up in two phases -

1. Delete the stack and ignore the `DELETE_FAILED` status **if just the lambda was failed to be deleted** (and the other resources were deleted successfully)
2. **Re-delete** the `DELETE_FAILED` stack after a few hours (Or do it automatically using a cleanup lambda triggered by cron event to clean-up the CloudFormation stacks with `DELETE_FAILED` status)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get in such a situation then yo most likely have freshly deleted a stack that did have lambda edge functions. In that case replicated functions get revealed (you dont see them while the edge function is inplace/being used). You dont need to do anything, just maybe to be patient - the replicated function will disappear after some time.